# My assertion fails for this piece of code in python

Tags: python, assert

```
def test_string_membership():
    assert False == 'c' in 'apple'
    assert True == 'a' in 'apple'
    assert True == 'app' in 'apple'
```

p.s:- I am a beginner in python and unable to find out whats wrong. My assertion fails when I run the code.

Comment: Even if you got the precedence right (e.g., with parentheses), this is not Pythonic, and overly complicated. You should almost never compare things to `True` or `False`; if you want to test if something is true, just do `if something`; if you want to test if it's false, `if not something`.

Comment: Also, the "put the constants on the left in any comparison" rule that you probably learned for C or a related language is not a good rule for Python. In C, accidentally writing `if (foo = 0)` when you meant `if (foo == 0)` silently does the wrong thing, while `if (0 = foo)` gives you an obvious error. But in Python, `if spam = 0` already gives you an obvious error, so this is unnecessary. And putting things in the natural order "if the thing I'm checking equals the value I expect" rather than backward makes your code more readable (at least to people used to Python code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`False == 'c' in 'apple'` is not interpreted as

```
False == ('c' in 'apple')
```

but,

```
(False == 'c') and ('c' in apple)
```

becaue of [comparison chaining](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in).

---

To get what you want, put parentheses explicitly.

```
False == ('c' in 'apple')
```

or more preferably use `in` / `not in`:

```
def test_string_membership():
    assert 'c' not in 'apple'
    assert 'a' in 'apple'
    assert 'app' in 'apple'
```

Comment: Specifically, `==` and `in` have the same level of precedence. Operators that have the same level of precedence are interpreted from left to right in the expression. http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: @paxdiablo: It's definitely not magically converting to `str` like that. If so, `2 in '123'` would be `True` instead of a `TypeError`.

Comment: This is incorrect, it is comparison chaining, not precedence.

Comment: But this answer isn't right either. You can see this by doing `ast.dump(ast.parse("False == 'c' in 'apple'"))`. It doesn't parse as `(False == 'c') in 'apple'`.

Comment: @BrenBarn, You're right. I slightly modified the sentence. now disassembling the function ..

Comment: @abarnert, I modified the sentence. Now seeing the output of `dis.dis(test_string_membership)`. Thank you for comment.

Comment: You don't need to do any disassembly, it's [in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in).

Comment: @BrenBarn, Thank you for pointing. I updated the answer according to you.

Comment: @BrenBarn, there's nothing wrong with looking at the disassembly or parse tree to understand what Python's doing if you can't figure it out yourself. You'll eventually need to go to the docs to write a definitive answer, but knowing which docs you're looking for can be a huge help…

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem with comparison chaining, the Python syntax that treats:

```
x < y < z
```

as:

```
x < y and y < z.
```

In your case, that means the expression `False == 'c' in 'apple'` is being treated as:

```
(False == 'c') and ('c' in 'apple')
```

both of which are false, hence causing the assertion. Details on comparison chaining for Python 3 can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in).

So the way to avoid this chianing is to make the expression explicit, with something like:

```
assert False == ('c' in 'apple')
assert True == ('a' in 'apple')
assert True == ('app' in 'apple')
```

or, even better, since comparing with `true/false` is rarely a good idea:

```
assert 'c' not in 'apple' # or "not('c' in 'apple')" if you're testing 'in'.
assert 'a' in 'apple'
assert 'app' in 'apple'
```

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to the other answers, what is happening here is not operator precedence but [comparison chaining](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in).  `a == b in c` means `(a == b) and (b in c)`, just like `a < b < c` means `(a < b) and (b < c)`.  However, in either case, the upshot is the same, which is that it's not what you meant to do.  As noted in the other answers and comments, it can be fixed by using parentheses, or, better, by not using an equality comparison at all and just doing `assert 'c' not in 'apple'`.

You can see that this is comparison chaining by a slightly different example:

```
>>> 'a' == 'a' in 'ab'
True
```

This would obviously be false no matter which way the precedence went, but it is true because `'a' == 'a'` and `'a' in 'ab'` are both true.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `()` in this case. There are better ways to do what you are trying.

```
def test_string_membership():
    assert False == ('c' in 'apple')
    assert True == ('a' in 'apple')
    assert True == ('app' in 'apple')
```

This is because of precedence. Read more about this on [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

`in, not in, is, is not, <, <=, >, >=, <>, !=, ==` are in the same precedence level. So Python will evaluate

```
False == 'c' in 'apple'
```

from left to right.

Comment: I wouldn't say you __must__ use `()` - `assert 'c' in 'apple' == False` would do what the OP expects. Or, as falsetru suggests, `assert 'c' not in 'apple'`

Answer (score 1):

Using parenthesis should solve this as in

```
def test_string_membership():
    assert False == ('c' in 'apple')
    assert True == ('a' in 'apple')
    assert True == ('app' in 'apple')
```